# Xcode Screen Orientation Problems

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I'm new to Xcode and programming for iOS, so I might not get what you're telling me, but try anyway. I'm creating an app for a school project, that will be all in Landscape orientation. In the storyboard, I add in many ViewControllers, to represent the different scenes, and they are all in Landscape mode. However, when I boot the emulator up, after the first scene, It switches to Portrait Orientation. My Supported Device Orientations are set as: Landscape Left, Landscape Right. In the storyboard, whilst selecting the ViewController, I have also changed the orientation to be Landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch [this you tube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ktSCCe-U8c) from "Geeky Lemon Development".

This will explain how to set your application to landscape.

It sets the devices start-up orientation to landscape.

Keep in mind that you must support both orientations (landscape and portrait) when developing an app for release on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the following code in every view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLefr)||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your orientation (UISupportedInterfaceOrientations) to the plist?